# How to change the font size for the contents of a cell created using javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

I have created a table using javascript . Here is the code

```
var table = document.createElement('TABLE');
table.border='1';
var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
table.appendChild(tableBody);
var tr = document.createElement('TR');
var td = document.createElement('TD');
newString = td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(newString));
tr.appendChild(td);
```

How do i change the font size of the cell contents ? ie  i want newString to be displayed in Font size 20.

Comment: How would you change it if it wasn't created dynamically, but by a static html?

Answer (score 4):

Add

```
td.style.fontSize = '20px';
```

After

```
var td = document.createElement('TD');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/RFCwt/